# Git - Recovering a commit after checking out of branch

Tags: git, github

I just started working with git and I am terrified that I might have lost a whole day hard of work. Could someone take a look and tell me if there is a way to recover that commit?

I was working on a branch. I did added files, commmited and performed a push to ANOTHER branch (I confused the branch names...) . Then did checkout to master because I wanted to merge everything. That's where I think screwed it up. Is there any way to recover files from my commit? Thanks

```
Yuri:Python yurir.tonin$ git checkout -b branch1_2files
M   .DS_Store
Switched to a new branch 'branch1_2files'
Yuri:Python yurir.tonin$ git status
On branch branch1_2files
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   .DS_Store
    modified:   GUI/dicomROI_more_files.py
    modified:   GUI/dicomROI_single_file.py

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
Yuri:Python yurir.tonin$ git  add .
Yuri:Python yurir.tonin$ git commit -m "Edited file dicomROI_more_files.py to receive and analyze data from multiple aquisitons, that is, from multiple folders containing DICOM images obtained at different flip angles)"
[branch1_2files 666a146] Edited file dicomROI_more_files.py to receive and analyze data from multiple aquisitons, that is, from multiple folders containing DICOM images obtained at different flip angles)
 3 files changed, 140 insertions(+), 53 deletions(-)
Yuri:Python yurir.tonin$ git push origin GUI_branch
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 1.10 KiB | 1.10 MiB/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), completed with 1 local object.
To https://github.com/yurirt94/TCC.git
 * [new branch]      GUI_branch -> GUI_branch
Yuri:Python yurir.tonin$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Yuri:Python yurir.tonin$ git merge GUI_branch
warning: Cannot merge binary files: .DS_Store (HEAD vs. GUI_branch)
Auto-merging GUI_old/dicomROI_v3.py
Auto-merging .DS_Store
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in .DS_Store
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
Yuri:Python yurir.tonin$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commit is still in your local `branch1_2files` branch.

Just abort the merge and go back to that branch

```
git merge --abort
git checkout branch1_2files
```

Now probably you should fix the wrong push and do the merge again

Answer (score 0):

If you committed into the branch you had checked out than you're good you just need to checkout that branch and you should be able to see your commit via git log.

```
>>> git checkout branch1_2files
>>> git log
```

You should not have been able to checkout of the branch you were working with and into master with pending changes ready to be staged, so I'm pretty sure you didn't wipe out your work.